# UTF-8 is encoding not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding

8 encoding is not working when i am fetching data from mysql table i have some special characters in database unable to fetch some cities with special characters like Østfold city and Ærø so when i type `ostfold` its not fetching `Østfold` city from database. while i am perfectly getting Šiauliai and Çorum from db when i write sia and cor respectively.

I have a city table i am getting cities from this table using jquery autocomplete ajax so when I type first three letters it shows me list of related letters I am working in CodeIgniter framwork.

my settings of **CodeIgniter** database.php :-

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

My database table city's column setting is :-

```
city_name(column name)  varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci(Collation)
```

Please help me anything else i have to change for this why i am unable to get cities starting with this characters like Ø and Æ.

Comment: you could try to change your query for SELECT city where city LIKE %city

Comment: can you show us what is the output of your current query using that characters ?

Comment: can you test 
print_r( $this->db->last_query() );

and share with us that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code i hope this will resolved your problem.

```
file_exists(mb_convert_encoding("file_å.txt", "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [collation table](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html) does not list Æ to be equal to A, neither does it list Ø to be equal to O.

You don't have an encoding problem (otherwise Çorum = corum wouldn't work), but instead an expectations problem. You expected them to be equal. By the definition of the collation table, they aren't.

Comment: so to do this what i have to do.

Comment: you can try to do a transliteration function to replace Ø to be equal to O and to "select name from city where name='Østfold' or name='Ostfold"

Answer (score 0):

See [Reference](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)

`Ø` = `O` for only one collation:  `utf8_unicode_520_ci`; most treat it like a letter between `O` and `P`.  A few collate it after `Z`.

`Æ` is a different matter.  It collates the same as the two letters `AE` in `utf8_unicode_520_ci` and at least one other collation.  Otherwise it is between `A` and `B` or after `Z`.

`Ç` is yet another matter.  It is equal to `C` for all collations *except* `utf8_turkish_ci`, in which case it is a letter between `C` and `D`.

`Š` = `S` for many collations; between `S` and `T` for some.

Bottom line:  Use `utf8_unicode_520_ci` for the column and the connection; type `Æ` as `AE`.